# Select option based on data that comes with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form I created for editing style on my html page. I pull the data into this form with ajax. And in my select box list, I want whatever data in the database is selected. Others will not disappear. The list will remain the same, but the data in the database will be selected. Somehow I couldn't. How can I do it?

read.php

```
case "magaza":

   if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])){
        $result = $mk_db->oku("magaza", " id='$id' ", "", "", "");
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $responseArray["marka_adi"] = $result[0]["marka_adi"];
            $responseArray["resim"] = $result[0]["resim"];
            $responseArray["durum"] = $result[0]["durum"];
            $responseArray["sira"] = $result[0]["sira"];
            echo json_encode($responseArray);
        }
    }
    break;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /********************** MODAL AÇMA **********************/
  $(document).on('click', '.bn-edit', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log("id:" + id + ",type:magaza");
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "read.php?id=" + id + "&type=magaza",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#edit-modal").modal('show');
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
          console.log("key:" + key + ",value:" + value);
        })
        $("#duz_sira").val(response.sira);
        $("#duz_durum").val(response.durum);
        $("#id").val(id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade duzenle" id="edit-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title pl-3" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Markayı Düzenle</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-white">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <form method="post" id="frmedit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body pre-scrollable">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control">
          <div class="form-group form-float mt-3">
            <div class="form-line">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duz_sira" name="duz_sira" required>
              <label class="form-label">Sıra</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control" name="duz_durum" id="duz_durum" required>
            <option>Durum Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="aktif">Aktif</option>
            <option value="pasif">Pasif</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn bg-grey waves-effect iptal-butonu" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
          <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn bg-purple waves-effect kaydet-butonu" value="Kaydet">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My console request:
[image]

Comment: Dear @mplungjan . The data of my selection is coming. I see it from Console, but I cannot selected the option in select.

Comment: See my answer - you missed an ID on the select. `$("#duz_durum")` uses the id. if you need name, you need `$("[name=duz_durum]")`

Answer (score 0):

Please study the post I made -  it is a [mcve] without any needless AJAX if the PHP works, it works and is not needed in the question

You need an ID on the select:

`$("#duz_durum")` uses the id. if you need name, you need `$("[name=duz_durum]")`

```js
const response = {
  "marka_adi": "Marka 2",
  "resim": "",
  "durum": "aktif",
  "sira": "3"
}
// $("#edit-modal").modal('show');
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
  console.log("key:" + key + ",value:" + value);
})
$("#duz_sira").val(response.sira);
$("#duz_durum").val(response.durum);
// $("#id").val(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade duzenle" id="edit-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title pl-3" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Markayı Düzenle</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-white">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <form method="post" id="frmedit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body pre-scrollable">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control">
          <div class="form-group form-float mt-3">
            <div class="form-line">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duz_sira" name="duz_sira" required>
              <label class="form-label">Sıra</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control" name="duz_durum" id="duz_durum" required>
            <option>Durum Seçiniz</option>
            <option value="aktif">Aktif</option>
            <option value="pasif">Pasif</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn bg-grey waves-effect iptal-butonu" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
          <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn bg-purple waves-effect kaydet-butonu" value="Kaydet">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that mean? You can see in my answer that if I use aktif in the object, the values are read

Comment: I send my console picture

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong. What framework are you using? There are no errors so perhaps the value is there but the framework hides it

Comment: I don't have any problem getting data anyway. My problem is to selected one of the options in the html according to the data I received.

Comment: I know Your example does not help me help you. Pleas rewrite your example like mine so we can see the actual data passed and how the actual rendered page looks like. For example you use some modal thing that can be bootstrap or jquery-UI  or something else

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good, i know. <option value="aktif" selected> or <option value="pasif" selected>.But this should come from database. but ı must ajax. Because ı ama doing to edit in modal.

Comment: I understand - the code works once you add an ID to the select!  - my example above works. I just hardcode the JSON into an object. The code works the same if we did ajax. You do not need the options from ajax, only which value to select

Comment: I have `<select class="form-control" name="duz_durum" id="duz_durum" required>` you have `<select class="form-control" name="duz_durum"  required>`

Comment: I edited it. In normally, I used select id. But ı fotgot when ı write here., sorry